# How do I use integer arithmetic to convert fractions into floating point numbers in python?

Tags: python, integer-arithmetic

What I need to do is use integer arithmetic to convert fractions into floating point numbers. The number of decimal places needed is specified as a variable `DECIMALS`. Each fraction is contained in a tuple of integers, for example `(1, 3)`.  The first item is the numerator and the second is the denominator. The tuples are contained in a list called `fractions`.

This is my code so far:

```
fractions = [(1,7), (2,3), (22,7), (7001,7), (9,3), (611951,611953), (1,11), (1,7689585)]

DECIMALS = 10**40 # 40 decimal places

for fraction in fractions:  
     x =  DECIMALS*fraction[0]/fraction[1]
     print x
```

When i run the code this is what i get:

```
1428571428571428571428571428571428571428
6666666666666666666666666666666666666666
31428571428571428571428571428571428571428   
10001428571428571428571428571428571428571428
30000000000000000000000000000000000000000
9999967317751526669531810449495304377950
909090909090909090909090909090909090909
1300460297922449651053990559958697
```

The problem is that I need to format this into the correct decimal format. What I tried was

```
print "0.%.40d" % (x)
```

But of course this will only help me with the first 2 decimals; the rest will be wrong. I thought about dividing it up so I can calculate the fractions indivdually to make them easier to format, but I have no idea how to do this. The catch is that all the fractions need to be processed by the same code. I also want it to be rounded properly but thats not a big deal right now.

Comment: It is very hard to figure what the question is here. Might http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html do what you want?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: ok so ive edited it and hopefully u guys will understand the question this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it strictly formatting, as implied by your question, you could, of course, do this with integers and strings alone:

```
def intF(n, d, l=40):
    s=str(n*10**l / d)
    if len(s) < l:
        return '0.{:0>{width}}'.format(s,width=l)
    if len(s) > l:
        return s[0:len(s)-l]+'.'+s[len(s)-l:] 

    return '0.'+s


for f in [(1,7), (2,3), (22,7), (7001,7), (9,3), 
          (611951,611953), (1,11),(1,7689585)]:
    print intF(*f)
    print float(f[0]) / f[1]
    print
```

Output:

```
0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428
0.142857142857

0.6666666666666666666666666666666666666666
0.666666666667

3.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428
3.14285714286

1000.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428
1000.14285714

3.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
3.0

0.9999967317751526669531810449495304377950
0.999996731775

0.0909090909090909090909090909090909090909
0.0909090909091

0.0000001300460297922449651053990559958697
1.30046029792e-07
```

The last digit will not correctly round and it will not handle edge cases ('inf', 'NaN', division by zero, etc) correctly.

Works in a pinch I suppose.

Why not use the batteries included though, like Decimal or Fraction?

Comment: im not sure i understand whats going on in the function nor in this part: print intF(*f). could u explain plz? and also whats a battery? im actually new to python and programming so i dont know what it is.

Comment: actually u dont need to explain the print intF(*f) anymore. i understand that part but i would still appreciate it if u could explain the function and more specifically whats happening in the i loops. thx

Comment: @321 I think the 'batteries' he referred to is the many selection of Python modules (like Decimal and Fraction) that do specialized tasks. It is said *batteries included* since Python has so many high quality modules to do specialized tasks. As part of your learning the language, learn these modules. Unless you are *really good* you should wonder why you are doing things differently than one of the distribution modules would have you do that task. The function does not have a loop. It only formats a string resulting from you suggested math. The only loop here is looping over your list by tuple

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this:

```
from fractions import Fraction
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 50

fractions = [(1,7), (2,3), (22,7), (7001,7), (9,3), (611951,611953), (1,11),(1,7689585)]

su=Fraction(0)
for i, t in enumerate(fractions,1):
    f=Fraction(*t)
    su+=Fraction(*t)
    d=decimal.Decimal(f.numerator) / decimal.Decimal(f.denominator)
    print '{} becomes {}'.format(t,f)
    print '\tfloat of that is: {}'.format(float(f))
    print '\tDecimal: {}'.format(d)
    print '\t{} elements cum sum of the list: {}\n'.format(i,su)
```

Prints:

```
(1, 7) becomes 1/7
    float of that is: 0.142857142857
    Decimal: 0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714
    1 elements cum sum of the list: 1/7

(2, 3) becomes 2/3
    float of that is: 0.666666666667
    Decimal: 0.66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667
    2 elements cum sum of the list: 17/21

(22, 7) becomes 22/7
    float of that is: 3.14285714286
    Decimal: 3.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571
    3 elements cum sum of the list: 83/21

(7001, 7) becomes 7001/7
    float of that is: 1000.14285714
    Decimal: 1000.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571429
    4 elements cum sum of the list: 21086/21

(9, 3) becomes 3
    float of that is: 3.0
    Decimal: 3
    5 elements cum sum of the list: 21149/21

(611951, 611953) becomes 611951/611953
    float of that is: 0.999996731775
    Decimal: 0.99999673177515266695318104494953043779505942449829
    6 elements cum sum of the list: 12955044968/12851013

(1, 11) becomes 1/11
    float of that is: 0.0909090909091
    Decimal: 0.090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909091
    7 elements cum sum of the list: 142518345661/141361143

(1, 7689585) becomes 1/7689585
    float of that is: 1.30046029792e-07
    Decimal: 1.3004602979224496510539905599586973809379829990825E-7
    8 elements cum sum of the list: 121767437017889092/120778724977295
```

The [fraction](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) module allows you to work with rational numbers (without converting to a float). Once you have put them into a Fraction class, you can do arithmetic with them (just like in grade school)

Like this:

```
>>> Fraction(1,3) + Fraction(3,4)
Fraction(13, 12)
>>> Fraction(1,3) + Fraction(1,6)
Fraction(1, 2)
>>> Fraction(1,2).numerator
1
>>> Fraction(1,2).denominator
2
```

The Fraction module is part of default Python distribution (since 2.6).

To convert that to a float, do `float(Fraction(17,18))` for example or use `Fraction.numerator` and `Fraction().denominator` in a Decimal class variable for arbitrary precision conversion.

Like so:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(su.numerator) / decimal.Decimal(su.denominator)
Decimal('1008.186144047968368606384293')
```

or:

```
>>> float(su.numerator) / su.denominator
1008.1861440479684
```

Comment: srry i cant do the float(#). i need to use pure integer arithmetic. like what i have done in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid floating point numbers in the first place.

```
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 50
>>> [str((decimal.Decimal(x) / decimal.Decimal(y)).quantize(decimal.Decimal(10) ** -40)) for (x, y) in FRACTIONS]
['0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429', '0.6666666666666666666666666666666666666667', '3.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429', '1000.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429', '3.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0.9999967317751526669531810449495304377951', '0.0909090909090909090909090909090909090909', '1.300460297922449651053990559958697E-7']
```